# Press Alt+< on a Hungarian keyboard (where < requires AltGr)

Tags: x11, emacs, keyboard-layout

I use a Hungarian keyboard layout. To type a less-than sign, I have to press: <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>í</kbd>.

By default, the Emacs Meta key is set to <kbd>Alt</kbd>, so I think I would have to press all of <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>í</kbd> at once.
But for some reason it seems that <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> cancel out each other, so this does nothing. I've tried it in terminal and under X too. <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>í</kbd> sends a `<`, but when I pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, the <kbd>í</kbd> key didn't send a new `KeyPress` event.

I'm using Lubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. I've selected the keyboard layout when I was installing the system using the graphical interface.

Comment: Are you running Emacs in a terminal or under X? What is your keyboard layout (nationality and any extra options)? Run the utility `xev` in a terminal and press `AltGr+í` and `AltGr+Alt+í`, what `KeyPress` eveents are sent?

Comment: @Gilles I've tried it in terminal and under X too. The keyboard layout is [`hu`](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/KB_Hungary.svg). [`AltGr+í`](http://pastebin.com/D0nVS4tj) sends a `"<"`, but when I pressed [`Alt` and `AltGr`](http://pastebin.com/B8AabUwt), the `í` key didn't send a new `KeyPress` event.

Comment: How did you select the Hungarian keyboard? (Different variants have different tweaks regarding modifiers.) What distribution are you using?

Comment: I'm using `Lubuntu 14.04.1 LTS`. I've selected the keyboard layout when I was installing the system using the graphical interface.

Comment: You should be able to use `Esc` instead of `Alt` fir emacs's `M` key.